# Prove that $f$ is a linear combination of $f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $f, f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n$ be linear maps from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $f(x)=0$ whenever $f_1(x)=f_2(x)=\cdots=f_n(x)=0$. Prove that $f$ is a linear combination of $f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n$.

The solution can be found [here (first problem).](http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc1998/prob_sol2.pdf).

but I disagree that $a_k$ is guaranteed to exist. What if the set containing all vectors $u\in V$ such that $f_1(u)=f_2(u)=\cdots =f_{k-1}(u)$ is empty?

Comment: But you don't want to choose $a_k=0$ as the solution will show that $f_k(a_k)\neq 0$.

Comment: Indeed @CalvinWoo, I quickly realized the foolishness of my comment and deleted it, haha. Thanks though!

Comment: (1) It's always true that $f_1(0) = \dots = f_{k-1}(0) = 0$. (2) If there is no $u$ such that  $f_1(u) = \dots = f_{k-1}(u) = 0$ and $f_k(u) \neq 0$ then $f_k$ is a linear combination of $f_1,\dots, f_k$ by the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Cool. I overlooked the fact that $0_V$ is always in the null space; so the set is never empty. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following. Let $V$ be an $K$-vector space ($K=\Bbb R$) of dimension say $m$. Let $V^*$ be its dual space. Now take $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n$ to  be linear forms in $V^*$, and let $\varphi$ be another form in $V^*$. You're assuming that $$\tag 1 \bigcap_{i=1}^n \ker\varphi_i\subseteq \ker \varphi$$

We may assume that the $n$ forms $\varphi_i$ are linearly independent. Extend them to a basis $$\{\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_{n},\varphi_{n+1},\ldots,\varphi_m\}$$

and let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n,v_{n+1},\ldots,v_m\}$ be its predual basis in $V$. Now write $$\varphi=\alpha_1\varphi_1+\cdots+\alpha_n\varphi_n+\alpha_{n+1}\varphi_{n+1}+\cdots+\alpha_m\varphi_m$$

By definition we have that $\varphi_j(v_i)=\delta_{ij}$. Use $(1)$ to show that $\alpha_{n+1}=\cdots=\alpha_m=0$.

Comment: What is "dual"? Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space

Comment: Peter: Great solution, but in the solution we have to assume $m\ge2$, right?

Comment: @user70520 Well, if $m=1$ things are boring, aren't they?

Comment: Sure. This dual space stuff makes the problem really easy!

Comment: I wonder why we do not consider $g=f_{k-1}+f_{k}$, which is also a linear map, and then apply the induction hypothesis for $f_1,f_2,\ldots, f_{k-2},g$?